# Elasticsearch Analysis token filter doesn't capture pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

I made a custom analyzer in my test index:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "myFilter": {
                "type": "pattern_capture",
                "patterns": ["\\d+(,\\d+)*(\\.\\d+)?[%$€£¥]?"],
                "preserve_original": 1
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
            "myAnalyzer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "myTokenizer",
                "filters":["myFilter"]
            }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
            "myTokenizer":{
                "type":"pattern",
                "pattern":"([^\\p{N}\\p{L}%$€£¥@#'\\-&]+)|((?<=[^\\p{L}])['\\-&]|^['\\-&]|['\\-&](?=[^\\p{L}])|['\\-&]$)|((?<=[^\\p{N}])[$€£¥%]|^[$€£¥%]|(?<=[$€£¥%])(?=\\d))"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

It is supposed to spit numbers like 123,234.56$ as a single token
But when such a number is provided it spits out 3 tokens 123 234 56$

The sample of failing test query:

```
GET test/Stam/_termvector?pretty=true 
{
    doc:{
            "Stam" : {
                "fld" : "John Doe",
                "txt": "100,234.54%"
            }
        },
        "per_field_analyzer" : {
            "Stam.txt": "myAnalyzer"
        },
        "fields" : ["Stam.txt"],
        "offsets":true,
        "positions":false,
        "payloads":false,
        "term_statistics":false,
        "field_statistics":false
    }
}
```

Can anyone figure out what is the reason?

Definitely for every other case ',' and '.' are delimiters, that is why I added a filter for that purpose, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple, token filter can not combine tokens by design. It should be done through char filters, that are applied to the char stream even before tokenizer starts to split to tokens.
I only had to make sure that the custom tokenizer will not split my tokens.